Javac thinks a lambda may actually be an instance of a class, "ambiguous call". Why?
Why can the Java compiler not compile this?
private ButtonGroup groupButtons(AbstractButton... buttons) {
    return groupButtons(() -> new ButtonGroup(), buttons);
}

private <BG extends ButtonGroup> BG groupButtons(Supplier<BG> buttonGroupSupplier, AbstractButton... buttons) {
    return groupButtons(buttonGroupSupplier.get(), buttons);
}

private <BG extends ButtonGroup> BG groupButtons(BG buttonGroup, AbstractButton... buttons) {
    for (AbstractButton button : buttons) {
        buttonGroup.add(button);
    }
    return buttonGroup;
}

It doesn't like the first call

Ambiguous method call.
Both groupButtons (Supplier, AbstractButton...) in FormItemTableEditDlg and
groupButtons(ButtonGroup, AbstractButton...) in FormItemTableEditDlg match

Nope, they don't!
It's clearly a lambda, not a javax.swing.ButtonGroup (it's not even an interface, which is plain as day even at compile-time).
Yes, I can cast, but I don't want to. It should be accepted by javac as is
Why is it ambiguous to Java?

The cause is your use of generics in those methods. The problem doesn't exist if you use Supplier<ButtonGroup> buttonGroupSupplier and ButtonGroup buttonGroup in those methods.

I don't want to dig further, but I guess this is because the lambda is defined based on its target type, and the target type is not really known at compile time due to this use of generics. Could this be solved? Probably. I guess they didn't want to address such an edge case, because - I guess - it can lead to other cascading issues with type inference.

This code compiles and runs in Eclipse, but not JDK22 javac

@DuncG Eclipse has its own compiler implementation, which may behave differently than the reference implementation, it might be a bug in ecj though that it compiles.

Like collection::add in the duplicate target, () -> new ButtonGroup() is not pertinent to applicability (for the third overload) for the exact same reason - its target type is a type parameter (BG).

That compiles correctly.
